# Loading image in ViewController from imagepicker -iphone

Tags: objective-c

Hi I tried a few solutions from this site but it isn't working for me. I am using the imagepicker to take a photo, then when the save button is enabled I want my `viewcontroller` Tag to load with that photo on it.

```
imagepicker.h

UIImageView * imagev;

imagepicker.m
-(IBAction)save:(id) sender {
Tag *tag= [[Tag alloc] initwithNibName...]
[self presentModalViewController:tag animated:YES]; 
tag.imageView=_imagev;  
}

Tag.h 

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;


Tag.m 

ViewDidLoad {
self.imageView.image=self.image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to overlay a picture over the camera, then you can make use of the cameraOverlayView property, which is a UIView and then set the overlay as

`myUIImagePicker.cameraOverlayView = myUIImageView;`

This will bring the image over the camera interface.

Comment: I want the picture taken to be loaded on the next viewcontroller when save is pressed